# Creating associations in Sequelize migration

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Nodejs. Sequelize 4.41. Try to make 2 models with relation many-to-many through another table. Running with *sequelize-cli*, for example...

```
sequelize model:generate --name Camera --attributes name:string,sn:string
```

Here is models

```
// Camera model

'use strict';

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Сamera = sequelize.define('Сamera', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    sn: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});
  Сamera.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
      Camera.belongsToMany(models.Relay, {through: 'CameraRelay'});
  };
  return Сamera;
};
```

And

```
// Relay model

'use strict';

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Relay = sequelize.define('Relay', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    sn: DataTypes.STRING,
    channel: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {});
  Relay.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
      Relay.belongsToMany(models.Camera, {through: 'CameraRelay'});
  };
  return Relay;
};
```

In documentation there are phrase

> Belongs-To-Many associations are used to connect sources with multiple targets. Furthermore the targets can also have connections to multiple sources.
>
> `Project.belongsToMany(User, {through: 'UserProject'});`
>   `User.belongsToMany(Project, {through: 'UserProject'});`
>
> This will
>   **create a new model called UserProject** with the equivalent foreign keys
>   projectId and userId.

Migrations is

```
// create-relay

'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Relays', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      sn: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      channel: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Relays');
  }
};
```

And

```
//create camera
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Сameras', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      sn: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Сameras');
  }
};
```

Why it doesn't create model CameraRelay and doesn't create migration for same model when I running migrate?

Answer (score 9):

I guess the misunderstanding is about **sync** vs **migration**: great part of documentation you are referring to, is using the **sync** method to create all tables and associations starting from models.

When you are using **migrations**, you are creating db all of your table/columns/associations using migration files (and in my hopinion, this is a better way for something that is going to production).

To understand the difference, just look at your camera model vs your camera migration file:

- the model has only `name` and `sn` properties defined
- the migration file has of course `name` and `sn`, but it has `id`, `createdAt` and `updatedAt` too.

Migrations are file with the aim of change your db in a safe way, allowing you to rollback to any point in the past.

So, back to your problem, you have to:

- create a new migration file to create your new CameraRelay table, with foreign keys to both Camera and Relay tables
- update your current Camera migration file with one-to-many relation to CameraRelay table
- update your current Relay migration file with one-to-many relation to CameraRelay table

CameraRelay migration example:

```
    'use strict';
    module.exports = {
      up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return queryInterface.createTable('CameraRelays', {
          cameraId: {
            primaryKey: true,
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            references: {        
              model: 'Relay',
              key: 'id'
            }
          },
          relayId: {
            primaryKey: true,
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            references: {         
              model: 'Camera',
              key: 'id'
            }
          },
          createdAt: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: Sequelize.DATE
          },
          updatedAt: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: Sequelize.DATE
          }
        });
      },
      down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return queryInterface.dropTable('CameraRelays');
      }
    };
```