# Does sequelize create constraints in the database?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

First of all, im used to work with Django as ORM framework, and django handles everything for me... creating of constraint, tables and etc... but when i saw that sequelize is a ORM framework i decided to give a change in one project mine using Express.

So far im using migrations, but i can tell that is way different from django way, i can generate a model and the first migrations from it with the cli, but i want to create the whole table with constraints and etc, there is a way to do that? or the functions "has" and "belong" only validate data from a backend perspective instead of really creating the constraints in the backend?

Other thing is i really have to do all my work twice using migrations? i mean configure my models and then configure all fields in migrations?

Last thing, there is a way to clear the database and re-run the migrations? without migrations i can use sync({force:true}) but that dont work with migrations.

```
'use strict'
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize')
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Foo extends Model {
    static associate (models) {
      models.Foo.belongsTo(models.Bar, { foreignKey: 'foo_id' });
    }
  };
  Foo.init({
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
      },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
    },
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'foo'
  })
  return Foo
}

const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize')
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Bar extends Model {
    static associate (models) { }
  };
  Bar.init({
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
      },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
    },
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'bar'
  })
  return Bar
}
```

**And the migrations is like**

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable('foo', {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
      },
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
      },
    })
  },
  // How can i create my constraints here?
  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('foo')
  }
};

module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable('bar', {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
      },
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
      },
      foo_id: {
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
      },
    })
  },

  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('bar')
  }
};
```

Comment: No, you only need to use migrations to modify the schema. Once you have the Models defined you can call `sequelize.sync()` to create the tables, or `sequelize.sync({ force: true })` to delete/recreate the tables.

Comment: Creating associations does create a relationship/constraint as well,  though you can disable them for the relationship by passing `{ constraints: false }` into the options.

Comment: i mean, i still on development stage, so i dont need to use migratiosn now?

Comment: You could if it's easier for you, but it sounds like it's just more work :) Keep in mind that it won't preserve the data if you do wipe it out with `force: true`

Comment: So something is happening with mine then, because after running my migrations (cleaning the database manually so the migrations can recreate the database) my foreign keys isnt being create at all

Comment: Your migration code doesn't create any associations, and in the Model it will only be create if you call `sync()`. Check out this answer for some more examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56365302/1427161

Comment: One other note, unless you are modifying the column names it best to let Sequelize generate things like primary keys.

Comment: oh i see...finally some clarity, so if i want to use migraitosn i should create constraints manually on migrations files, or if im using sync i can do it without creating manually, thank you :)

Comment: Yep, exactly. One last note that I just saw - I think you want to use `models.Foo.belongsTo()` not `belongsToOne()`.

Comment: no worries, this foo bar was just a draft, i was using belongsToMany and i re-typed without checking the right sintaxe, but ty anyways